# Removing NULL value in SQL JOIN and UNION Operators in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, isnull

[SOLVED] how to remove the NULL value only in the field **provider_order** only, in my case the table was using JOIN Table and UNION

Here is my database schema and My SQL Query

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f77862/2

To clearly describe here i attach the picture

[The  red line circle is which should be removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMGsl.jpg)

Comment: If you're satisfied that the problem is solved, please mark it as such by accepting an answer or otherwise delete the question, brotha.

Comment: thanks brotha. already marked.. thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not remove only that field in a row. However, you can get rid of the entire row simply by using a WHERE clause to filter out records with null values.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f77862/42

```
SELECT
    m.provider_id,
    m.provider_name,
    p.purchase_order_code,
    NULL AS purchase_order_sample_code,
    p.provider_id AS provider_order
FROM mst_provider AS m
LEFT JOIN trx_purchase_order AS p
    ON (m.provider_id = p.provider_id)
WHERE p.provider_id != NULL
UNION
SELECT
    m.provider_id,
    m.provider_name,
    p.purchase_order_code,
    NULL AS purchase_order_sample_code,
    p.provider_id AS provider_order
FROM mst_provider AS m
RIGHT JOIN trx_purchase_order AS p
    ON (m.provider_id = p.provider_id)
UNION
SELECT
    m.provider_id,
    m.provider_name,
    NULL,
    s.purchase_order_sample_code,
    s.provider_id
FROM mst_provider AS m
RIGHT JOIN trx_purchase_order_sample AS s
    ON (s.provider_id = m.provider_id)
```

Comment: this is what i expect, MANY THANKS brother

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by remove? Removing entire row or just displaying something else other than NULL in provider_order. If you are looking for later, then you can use [COALESCE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp)

Edit : Made changes in your fiddle only : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f77862/46

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you want to filter where provider_order is null?

I wrapped your entire query as a subquery, and placed a where clause at the end, returning only records where provider_order is not null.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f77862/50/0

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT m.provider_id,
        m.provider_name,
        p.purchase_order_code,
        NULL AS purchase_order_sample_code,
        p.provider_id AS provider_order
    FROM mst_provider AS m
    LEFT JOIN trx_purchase_order AS p
        ON (m.provider_id = p.provider_id)

    UNION

    SELECT m.provider_id,
        m.provider_name,
        p.purchase_order_code,
        NULL AS purchase_order_sample_code,
        p.provider_id AS provider_order
    FROM mst_provider AS m
    RIGHT JOIN trx_purchase_order AS p
        ON (m.provider_id = p.provider_id)

    UNION

    SELECT m.provider_id,
        m.provider_name,
        NULL,
        s.purchase_order_sample_code,
        s.provider_id
    FROM mst_provider AS m
    RIGHT JOIN trx_purchase_order_sample AS s
        ON (s.provider_id = m.provider_id)
    ) _temp
WHERE provider_order IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: An another solution, thanks brotha... the problem already solved :-)

Comment: Lol I know I saw the other answer it was the same time I posted this one. This one only has one where clause, the other answer as three. I figured to give you a solution that closely resembles your code more, than injecting code in the middle of it.